# pytest не запускается

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Начал изучать тестирование в Python, а именно модуль pytest. Установил через pip, но при запуске получил ошибку.
[image: Имя "pytest" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.]

Попытка запустить pytest через python -m pytest filename, выдает целый ряд ошибок во многих системных файлах, в т.ч. в main.py

[image: Очевидно тут проблемы с userDict, в файле main.py, которого по идее быть не должно]

Использую VisualStudio, Windows 10, Python версии 3.11.4.

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: вы установили модуль от администратора или как локальный пользователь? возможно. причина в этом.

Comment: Папка, где находится pytest (скорее всего python/Scripts) не добавлена в переменную окружения path.

Comment: Прошу прощения за нубский вопрос, а как ее можно добавить?

Comment: По ошибкам такое впечатление, что установлен pytest для более старой версии python. Пробуйте его обновить: `pip install -U pytest`